# Installing bigfloat, GMP and MPFR in windows for python

Tags: python, installation, gmp, mpfr, bigfloat

I am trying to install bigfloat in Python 3.2 on a Windows 7 machine. The documentation says that I first need to install GMP and MPFR. I have downloaded both of these to my desktop (as well as the bigfloat package). However as they are C packages I am not sure how to install them in python (I have tried to find a clear explanation for the last several hours and failed). Can any one either tell me what I need to do or point me to a tutorial? Thanks a lot, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid that you can't install it the way you have tried so far, simply because you need to compile the C files. Instead, what you can do is download from the unofficial binaries for windows:

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Go the the site, and search for your packages. There are several versions of them, so make sure that you have the right versions for the Python that you're using.

Comment: Thanks. However I went to the link you suggested, downloaded and ran gmpy (which said it was a wrapper for both gmp and mpfr) but when I tried to install bigfloat (via python setup.py install in the same directory) it said fatal error gmp.h: No such file or directory

Comment: Then you are going to have to build all your libraries. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711315/build-gmp-on-64bit-windows

Answer (score 1):

There are two versions of gmpy - version 1 (aka gmpy) and version 2 (aka gmpy2). gmpy2 includes MPFR. If you install gmpy2 then you probably don't need bigfloat since the functionality of MPFR can be directly accessed from gmpy2.

Disclaimer: I maintain gmpy and gmpy2.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found a solution..
go to the link http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#bigfloat 
get the proper package installed(depends on 32 bits or 64 bits)
go to command prompt
type \name_of_the_file.whl
eg: C:\python27\pip install bigfloat-0.3.0-cp27-none-win32.whl